# Python two loops

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

I am trying to create a game where two user enters letters until they guess the secret word, but for some reason my lists are not updating properly. Lets say the secret word is TOYS, if the user guesses T it displays T _ _ _ and then the user enters R so it switches to the secondLoop and the user enters S it says that S is not in the word and goes to first user.
This is a guess game that changes between two players and when it changes to second player it doesnt work for some reason. Cant figure out why.The Function secondLoop has the same components with the additional lines "#"

Comment: Either you did not format your code properly when posting or your indentation is out of whack.

Comment: Why haven't you got a colon after the first while loop?

Comment: Not yet, there should be an indent after the first while. Please copy the exact code of your script (you do use 4 spaces for indenting everywhere, I hope?), paste it in the editor, select it and press CTRL+K to format it as code.

Comment: @BasSwinckels does it look okay to work with now?

Comment: @BasSwinckels do you have any idea how to fix this code

Comment: The line after the while loop needs to be indented. My advice would be to build your program slowly since you are a novice programmer.

Comment: @I.K. i have fixed all the indents. none of that is the problem. my code works except for when it calls the second function. it messes up there and i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

In your secondLoop function it appears to be calling itself recursively forever.  That may be what is causing your error.  I changed the recursive self call to a return statement and it seems to work fine.  I've commented the changes below for example...

```
def secondLoop(enteredLetters,sentence,newSentence,lettersInWord):
    print '--Player 2--'
    number = len(sentence)
    flag = True
    while flag == True: 
        # changed input to raw_input
        letter = raw_input("Enter letter: ")

        if letter not in enteredLetters:
            find = sentence.find(letter)
            if find == -1:
                print("Letter is not in word")
                flag = False
                # --- changed line below to return statement below it ---
                #enteredLetters,newSentence,lettersInWord = secondLoop(enteredLetters,sentence,newSentence,lettersInWord)
                return enteredLetters,newSentence,lettersInWord
            else:
                newSentence = ""
                lettersInWord.append(letter)
                for char in sentence:
                    if char in lettersInWord:
                        newSentence = newSentence + char 
                    else:
                        newSentence = newSentence + "_ "
                number = newSentence.count("_")
                flag = True
        elif letter in enteredLetters:
            print ("The letter has been used")
            flag = False
            # --- changed line below to return statement below it ---
            #enteredLetters,newSentence,lettersInWord = secondLoop(enteredLetters,sentence,newSentence,lettersInWord)
            return enteredLetters,newSentence,lettersInWord

        print (newSentence)
        enteredLetters.append(letter)    

sentence = 'TOYS'
enteredLetters = []
newSentence = '____'
lettersInWord = []

number = len(sentence)
while number != 0:
    print '--Player 1--'
    # changed input to raw_input
    letter = raw_input("Enter letter: ")

    if letter not in enteredLetters:
        find = sentence.find(letter)
        if find == -1:
            print("Letter is not in word")
            enteredLetters,newSentence,lettersInWord = secondLoop(enteredLetters,sentence,newSentence,lettersInWord)
        else:
            newSentence = ""
            lettersInWord.append(letter)
            for char in sentence:
                if char in lettersInWord:
                    newSentence = newSentence + char 
                else:
                    newSentence = newSentence + "_ "
            number = newSentence.count("_")
    elif letter in enteredLetters:
        print ("The letter has been used")
        enteredLetters,newSentence,lettersInWord = secondLoop(enteredLetters,sentence,newSentence,lettersInWord)
    print (newSentence)
    enteredLetters.append(letter)
```

Comment: No I did not mean that when I put those statements in my function is the entire code I put with the comments, and the function is not calling itself, that was a line in main just to call the function

Comment: The edits you made still do not seem to work, and i dont know why if calling the function is the same thing as main. if it is just one player the code works perfectly, but once I make the call to the second function it messes up

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your stack trace/error message?

Answer (score 0):

Good program structure makes life so much easier:

```
from itertools import cycle
import string

UNKNOWN     = "_"
ALWAYS_SEEN = set(" " + string.punctuation)

def get_letter(prompt):
    while True:
        ch = input(prompt).strip().upper()
        if len(ch) == 1:
            return ch

def seen_word(word, guessed):
    return ''.join(ch if ch in guessed or ch in ALWAYS_SEEN else UNKNOWN for ch in word)

def play_hangman(word, players):
    word    = word.strip().upper()
    guessed = set()
    seen    = seen_word(word, guessed)

    for current_player in cycle(players):
        while True:
            print(seen)
            ch = get_letter("{}: guess a letter: ".format(current_player))

            if ch in guessed:
                print("That letter has already been guessed!")
                break
            else:
                guessed.add(ch)

            if ch in word:
                print("That's the way to do it!")
                seen = seen_word(word, guessed)
            else:
                print("Sorry, that letter is not in the word.")
                break

            if seen == word:
                print("Hurray! {} won!".format(current_player))
                return current_player

def main():
    word = "TOYS"
    players = ["Player 1", "Player 2"]
    play_hangman(word, players)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```